# How to extract users rating

Tags: support, api, users, stackoverflow

I need a solution to exact reputations, badges for the stack overflow users. Please let me know. In microsoft programming language should be fine.

Comment: In what programming language? Wait, what's rating? Is that included in the documentation, if yes then where...?